# Why code disappeared after merge? Do I need to rebase?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm not a native speaker of English, but I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

I merged branch to master, but some code is disappeared without any complain or conflict.

1. 1/14 - add code A at Resouce.java
2. 1/22 - master merge code A
3. 1/28 - master merges Resouce.java that adds code B and code A is gone from master.

***Please check the attached image!!***

It happened all the time like the below command

```
git checkout child1
git merge child2
```

Before Merge, I can rebase ​child1 to child2.
But, I learn I do not use rebase like in this situation.

why this is happening?

Thank you for reading my poor English

[image]

Comment: I assume this is what happened - You added code A and pushed to master branch. Then someone else added code B and pushed it to master branch. And now when you try to merge from the master branch code A is lost. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks like whoever merged last "solved" the conflict by just taking their own changes.

Comment: @GauthamM Yes,Thas's correct. I really dont understand how code can be disappeared...

Comment: @suhwanlim Are you sure that the other person who pushed code B to master branch did not remove code A?

Comment: @GauthamM Yes, When Code B added to master, Code A doesn't exist at Child1. So, It's impossible to delete

Comment: @GauthamM sorry, fix typo `When Code B added to master ` -> `When Code B added to Child1(branch) `

Comment: @GauthamM  Thank you, guys! I served this problem. the reason is child1 rebased by child2 without code A... thank you so much!